# Can you add code examples to toggle switches for the right-label class

Tags: vmware-clarity, toggleswitch

Your toggles.demo.html in your documentation needs a section show the usage of the supported right-label class. Generally speaking, the .toggle-switch.right-label class isn't documented anywhere. We found out about it by digging into the code.

```
<section class="form-block">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="formGroupExampleInput">Right Label Toggles</label>
        <div class="toggle-switch right-label">
            <input type="checkbox" id="toggle_4">
            <label for="toggle_4">Toggles turn on and off</label>
        </div>
        <div class="toggle-switch right-label">
            <input type="checkbox" id="toggle_5" disabled>
            <label for="toggle_5">Toggle off and disabled</label>
        </div>
        <div class="toggle-switch right-label">
            <input type="checkbox" id="toggle_6" checked disabled>
            <label for="toggle_6">Toggle on and disabled</label>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Hi there. I created an issue to add this to the Toggle documentation. SO is for questions and this seems to be more like an enhancement request to the docs I'll just leave a link to the issue. Please feel free to add more informatin there and subscribe to it for more updates. https://github.com/vmware/clarity/issues/2386